# Conditional hiding of several columns in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

I'm trying to create a list where contact details of stakeholders are associated with a number of projects. Sometimes it is only 1 project and sometimes it is up to five different projects.

Currently I have the following columns:

Stakeholder name (from Active Directory) and then Project Name 1, Project Name 2, project Name 3 etc. (all from a lookup table).

What I tried to do is to add a supplementary column named 'Add Project Name 2?' with a choice of 'Yes' and 'No'. If 'Yes' is selected, I'd like a 'Project Name 2' column to appear. And so on.

After some researching I tried a custom formula of:

```
=if([$Add Project Name 2?] == 'Yes', 'true', 'false')
```

However, this hasn't worked for me. Would you have any advice on where I am going wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "Add Project Name 2?" column is of type **Choice**, Use formula like:

```
=if([$InternalNameOfAddProjectName2Column] == 'Yes', 'true', 'false')
```

In case of **Yes or No** (boolean) column, use:

```
=if([$InternalNameOfAddProjectName2Column], 'true', 'false')
```

Make sure you are using correct **internal name** of column in your formula as it works with internal name only.

> The column is represented by specifying the **internal name** of the field surrounded by square brackets and preceded by a dollar sign: [$InternalName]. For example, to get the value of a field with an internal name of "ProductName", use `[$ProductName]`.

**References**

1. [Find the internal name of SharePoint column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)
2. [Show or hide columns in a list or library form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh for your help. I have tried both options but unfortunately it's still showing all columns. I even tried a different browser but it's still the same.

Comment: Can you show us the internal name of your column and where exactly you are adding this formula (add screenshot to your original question)? Also, you have to add formula for all the columns you want to show/hide based on other column values.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh - I have added a number of images - I hope this will help

Comment: You are adding formula in wrong place. Follow the steps given in this documentation for adding formula in correct place: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide

Comment: Let me know if it works or you still need any help with this.

Comment: Thank you - perfect! All works as intended! Many thanks for yoru guidance and prompt responses!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked for you!